# Learning Linq to XML and trying to create an object from xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am in the process of learning LINQ to XML.

Say I have an xml like this:

```
<main>
    <machine>
            <car name="HONDA">
                <model name="ACCORD"/>
            </car>
            <car name="HONDA">
                <model name="CRV"/>
            </car>
            <car name="FORD">
                <model name="FOCUS"/>
            </car>
            etc.......        
    </machine>
</main>
```

I have an object called:

```
public class MyCar
{
    public MyCar() { }
    public MyCar(string m1, string m2)
    {
        Make = m1;
        Model = m2;
    }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model{ get; set; }
}
```

Using LINQ how can I accomplish setting the "Model" in my statement?

```
    var cars = from g in doc.Elements("main").Descendants("machine")
                 select g;
    var listCars = from c in cars.Descendants("car")
                 select new MyCar
                 {
                     Make = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                     Model= ""
                 };
```

I am using 4.0 framework.

Comment: ``c.Descendants("model").First().Attribute("name").Value``

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't using .First() when I originally tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var listCars = from c in cars.Descendants("car")
               select new MyCar
               {
                  Make = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                  Model= c.Element("model").Attribute("name").Value
               };
```

### Update

If you change your xml schema to something like you show in your comment, you can filter your cars, for example, this way:

```
var listCars = from c in cars.Descendants("car")
               let doors= c.Elements("model").FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Attribute("name").Value=="doors")
               where doors!=null && doors.Value=="4 Doors"// this way you can get the cars that only have 4 doors
               select new MyCar
               {
                  Make = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                 //...
               };
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a where clause on the Model statement if the xml changed? Ex. <car name="HONDA"><model name="model"/>Accord<model name="doors"/>4 Doors</car>

Comment: In this case I would find the "Car" element and load its value, then load any additional values from the children of the car based upon checking the attribute value "name" to determine what the value of the element is.

Comment: Thank you for examples.  This should help me start to understand what I can/cant do with linq to xml.